# .htaccess redirect GET parameters and PDFs

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, parameters

I have a few links from an old site - asp files with parameters in querystring - I wan them redirected to my new WordPress site.

For Example

http://www.example.com/admin/m_sito/sample/down.asp?file=catalogue_de.pdf
to
http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/doc/catalogue_de.pdf.pdf

here is the code that is not working with variables in them. Any ideas?

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^file=catalogue_de.pdf$
RewriteRule ^admin/m_sito/sample/down\.asp$ /wp-content/uploads/doc/catalogue_de? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: can you please try my answer?

Comment: can you please accept and upvote on answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

You should try this answer :-

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/admin/m_sito/sample/down\.asp$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^file=catalogue_de.pdf$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wp-content/uploads/doc/catalogue_de [R=302,L]
```

For the General case you can use this :-

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/admin/m_sito/sample/down\.asp$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^file=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wp-content/uploads/doc/%1.pdf [R=302,L]
```

May me it will helpful.

Comment: I don't think the REQUEST_URI matches.

Comment: @ErkiA can you suggest me what is my mistake there?

Comment: i'm trying with RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/admin/m_sito/sample/down\.asp$  ..-but it doesn't work :(

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/down\.asp$

Comment: can you please try this only?

Comment: can you please try now?

Comment: @Anita can you please accept and upvote on answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

A little bit improved version of Harsh Sanghani's answer:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin/m_sito/sample/down\.asp$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^file=(.*)$
RewriteRule .* /wp-content/uploads/doc/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I think she wants to redirect to their wordpess site, How is it possible with this?

Comment: I understand that the wordpress site is on the same domain as the old site. So these lines should be added to the .htaccess file in the root of the wordpress site.

Comment: it works!!! thank you Erki and Harsh. I moved the code at the begin of the file and it works :) yehaaaa

Answer (score 0):

I moved the code at the begin of the .htaccess file and it works

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin/m_sito/sample/down\.asp$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^file=(.*)$
RewriteRule .* /wp-content/uploads/doc/%1? [R=301,L]
```

thank you very much :)